# Sending Buttons to the back of Layout

Tags: java, android, layout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to add List Session header and add hidden buttons at the back.

Kindly help me to send Del Button and Edit Button to back of session header. It will be viewed after a swipe.

I also tried bringToFront and sendToBack on buttons which dint work.

To Set Z Order, I need to set Project min SDK to 21 which I dont want to do. SO I cant use Z order also.

```
 RelativeLayout SupRelLyoVar = new RelativeLayout(KxtVar);
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams NamLysHtrRloRulVaj = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LyHtrHytVal);
 SupRelLyoVar.setLayoutParams(NamLysHtrRloRulVaj);

 Button DelBtnVav = new Button(KxtVar);
 DelBtnVav.setId(View.generateViewId());
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams DelBtnRulVaj = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LyHtrHytVal, LyHtrHytVal);
 DelBtnRulVaj.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
 DelBtnVav.setLayoutParams(DelBtnRulVaj);
 SupRelLyoVar.addView(DelBtnVav);

 Button EdtBtnVav = new Button(KxtVar);
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams EdtBtnRulVaj = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LyHtrHytVal, LyHtrHytVal);
 EdtBtnRulVaj.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, DelBtnVav.getId());
 EdtBtnVav.setLayoutParams(EdtBtnRulVaj);
 SupRelLyoVar.addView(EdtBtnVav);

 LinearLayout LnrLyoVar = new LinearLayout(KxtVar);
 LnrLyoVar.setBackgroundColor(SsnHtrBgdClr);
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams LnrLyoRulVaj = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LyHtrHytVal);
 LnrLyoRulVaj.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

 TextView TxtVyuVav = new TextView(KxtVar);
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams LysHtrTxtVyuRulVaj = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 TxtVyuVav.setLayoutParams(LysHtrTxtVyuRulVaj);
 LnrLyoVar.addView(TxtVyuVav);

 SupRelLyoVar.addView(LnrLyoVar, LnrLyoRulVaj);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got solution and like to post 
This is for all whom I wish not to struggle like me.

|*| Set OnTouchListener :

```
LnrLyoVar.setOnTouchListener(WkaMovLitRitVyuKlkVaf);
```

|*| Use below outside function :

```
View.OnTouchListener WkaMovLitRitVyuKlkVaf = new View.OnTouchListener()
{
    float WkaStrVyuXcoVar, WkaStrTchXcoVar, WkaStpTchXcoVar;
    final int MovDstVar = LloHytVal * 2;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams EdtBtnRulVaj, DelBtnRulVaj;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View VyuPsgVar, MotionEvent MsnEvtPsgVar)
    {
        switch (MsnEvtPsgVar.getActionMasked())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                WkaStrTchXcoVar = MsnEvtPsgVar.getRawX();
                WkaStrVyuXcoVar = (int) VyuPsgVar.getX();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                WkaStpTchXcoVar = MsnEvtPsgVar.getRawX();
                float XcoDstVar = Math.abs(WkaStpTchXcoVar - WkaStrTchXcoVar);

                if (XcoDstVar < MovDstVar)
                {
                    EdtBtnRulVaj = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) NamEdtBtnVav.getLayoutParams();
                    DelBtnRulVaj = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) NamDelBtnVav.getLayoutParams();
                    int SetBtnWytVar;
                    if (WkaStrVyuXcoVar == 0)
                    {
                        VyuPsgVar.animate()
                                .translationX(-XcoDstVar)
                                .setDuration(0)
                                .start();
                        SetBtnWytVar = (int) XcoDstVar / 2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        VyuPsgVar.animate()
                                .x(-MovDstVar + XcoDstVar)
                                .setDuration(0)
                                .start();
                        SetBtnWytVar = (int) (LloHytVal - XcoDstVar / 2);
                    }
                    DelBtnRulVaj.width = SetBtnWytVar;
                    EdtBtnRulVaj.width = SetBtnWytVar;
                    NamEdtBtnVav.setLayoutParams(EdtBtnRulVaj);
                    NamDelBtnVav.setLayoutParams(DelBtnRulVaj);
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                EdtBtnRulVaj = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) NamEdtBtnVav.getLayoutParams();
                DelBtnRulVaj = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) NamDelBtnVav.getLayoutParams();
                int SetBtnWytVar = 0;
                if (WkaStrVyuXcoVar == 0 && WkaStpTchXcoVar < WkaStrTchXcoVar)
                {
                    VyuPsgVar.animate()
                            .x(-MovDstVar);
                    SetBtnWytVar = LloHytVal;
                }
                else if (WkaStrVyuXcoVar == -MovDstVar)
                {
                    VyuPsgVar.animate()
                            .x(0);
                    SetBtnWytVar = 0;
                }
                DelBtnRulVaj.width = SetBtnWytVar;
                EdtBtnRulVaj.width = SetBtnWytVar;
                NamEdtBtnVav.setLayoutParams(EdtBtnRulVaj);
                NamDelBtnVav.setLayoutParams(DelBtnRulVaj);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```